# Amazon ElasticBeanstalk - failed To Terminate Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I try to terminate an environment in Amazon ElasticBeanstalk I get an error  as follows

> Deleting security group named:  failed Reason: API: ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message:  dsfdgdfsgfgsd

If I try to delete the security group manually I get a similar error.
However my account has full permissions.
I tried this via the command line also with no joy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That kind of error typically indicates that the account you're using does not have the right IAM permissions.  If you're using the root AWS account (which you generally shouldn't do), you shouldn't get this at all and will need to post on the AWS forums.  If you're using your personal IAM login, the most likely explanation is missing IAM permissions.

Answer (score 0):

@Josh Padnick - thanks for your help

I checked my own IAM account and had admin, poweruser privileges, deleted security group on EC2 but none of these worked

I asked the root user to delete the environments question and it worked no problem